# Combining 1 item from 2 SharePoint lists

Tags: caml, query

I have SPList A which has the columns: Title, Description, Category.
 and SPList B which has the following columns: Column1, Column2, Category.

I want to make one object for items with the same category to be able to use it to combine to gridview later, any help?

Answer (score 1):

You can only join list in CAML if one of the lists contain a lookup field into the other list.

If one of your lists only contain one item per Category then you can make the category in the other list a lookup into the first list and then you can use [List Joins and Projections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee539975%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

If both list can contain multiple items per category then CAML can't help you. Depending on the number of items in your list you have to do one of following:

- retrieve all elements of both lists and do the join in memory
- retrieve all elements from one of the list, the needed elements from the other and do the join in memory
- retrieve the needed elements from one of the list and for each element retrieve the matching elements in the other list